# More contemporary resource for Greenberg

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, online-resources

Is there a more modern textbook than Greenberg's forms in many variables, or a set of notes, that summarizes the developments about $C_i$ fields? Is there such a thing as $C_i$ field where $i$ is not an integer?